# CodeMirror : how to limit height in editor

Tags: codemirror

I am using [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) to show some code on a webpage. But when I initialize the codemirror editor, the height of the editor is way more than the number of lines in the code. Please [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitirajrathore/4nvL65L2/1/) or below image to understand what I am saying  [image: screen shot of extra height in code mirror]  Below is the code to create the codemirror editor.

```
var myCodeArea = document.getElementById("codeArea");
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
  myCodeArea.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, myCodeArea);
}, {value: myCodeArea.innerHTML,
   lineNumbers:true, mode:"javascript"});
```

I read codemirror doc but not able to figure out which property controls the height.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The height can be set through CSS (by giving the `.CodeMirror` class a `height` property), or by calling the editor's `setSize` method.

If you want the editor height to correspond to the height of it's contents, see [this demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html).

Answer (score 5):

Might help someone.

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea"></textarea>
```

.

```
var config, editor;

            config = {                  
                lineNumbers: true,
                mode: "text/javascript",
                lineWrapping: true,
                htmlMode: true,
                matchClosing: true,       
                indentWithTabs: true,
                readOnly: true
            };


            editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("exampleTextarea"), config);
            editor.setSize(900,"100%");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you see your fiddle, there is an entry in css which defines height.

```
.CodeMirror {


 /* Set height, width, borders, and global font properties here */
    font-family: monospace;
    height: 300px;
}
```

You can either override this css or use setSize(width,height) method of codemirror.