# Codemirror autoresize upto a given number of lines

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I'm trying to allow codemirror to autoresize up to a given number of lines or pixel height. After this max-size is reached the widget should add scrollbars.

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
   lineNumbers: true,
   viewportMargin: 50
```

});

max-height is not working

```
.CodeMirror {
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qzjo4ejh/

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378229/codemirror-how-to-limit-height-in-editor

Comment: nop, it's not a fixed size but a resizable with a max what I'm looking for

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should give `.CodeMirror` a `height: auto` style, and put the `max-height` on `.CodeMirror-scroll`. The embedded editor on the [project page](http://codemirror.net) does this (view source, it's right near the top).

Comment: Thanks a lot, paypal donation would be handy ;-)

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. Please consider adding it to the documentation in an easy to find place.

Comment: This works great to make the use of CodeMirror in TeamCity bigger using something like Stylebot.  Here is my minimal css change to get a bigger coding window: `.CodeMirror {
  height:auto;
}

.CodeMirror-scroll {
  max-height: 700px;
}

td.codeHighlightTD {
  height: 800px;
}`

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me. The `CodeMirror-scroll` was causing it to size itself way too big. You don't need to do anything with `viewportMargin` despite what the docs say.

```
.CodeMirror {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: auto;
    max-height:100px;
}

.CodeMirror-scroll {
    height: auto;
    max-height:100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qazg5j9/2/)

Comment: the auto height on .CodeMirror-scroll just saved my day, without that the editor would always just show 100% height. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What about something like that :

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
   lineNumbers: true,
   viewportMargin: 50
});

var height;
if(myCodeMirror.lineCount() > 5) {
    height = 50;
} else {
    height = 20 * myCodeMirror.lineCount();
}
myCodeMirror.setSize(500, height);
```

This is an example. You can handle an event to dynamically resize your CodeMirror when lines change.

Comment: you can try in fiddle, it's not working as expected.

Comment: Tested in fiddle, it works perfectly. just have to set other lines of text and 20 instead of 10px by line

Comment: Check the answer of Marijn (he is  the owner of the project). Nonetheless thanks for you effort.